# Edit database wont work with added code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `nbabdl_spiller` - where players are stored. The player table have:

```
spiller_id
spiller_navn (player name)
spiller_position
spiller_ligahold (player league team)
spiller_alder (player age)
spiller_lon1 (player salary year 1)
spiller_lon2
spiller_lon3.
```

I can create the players just fine - but I can only edit the player if the fields `spiller_id`, `spiller_navn`, `spiller_position` and `spiller_alder` are used - when I try to add more in `bdl_update.php`, it just sends me back to `bdl_index.php` without changes.

What am I doing wrong? I tried reading about `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, but that didn't help me.

First, the code that is working, then the one that isn't and finally `bdl_index.php` where you can see the fields/variables:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'bdl_config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$spiller_navn = $spiller_position = $spiller_alder = "";
$spiller_navn_err = $spiller_position_err = $spiller_alder_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["spiller_id"]) && !empty($_POST["spiller_id"])){
// Get hidden input value
$spiller_id = $_POST["spiller_id"];

// Validate Navn
$input_spiller_navn = trim($_POST["spiller_navn"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_navn)){
    $spiller_navn_err = "Angiv venligst et navn.";
} elseif(!filter_var(trim($_POST["spiller_navn"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z'-.\s ]+$/")))){
    $spiller_navn_err = 'Angiv venligst et gyldigt navn.';
} else{
    $spiller_navn = $input_spiller_navn;
}

// Validate Position
$input_spiller_position = trim($_POST["spiller_position"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_position)){
    $spiller_position_err = 'Angiv venligst en position.';     
} else{
    $spiller_position = $input_spiller_position;
}

// Validate Alder
$input_spiller_alder = trim($_POST["spiller_alder"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_alder)){
    $spiller_alder_err = "Angiv venligst en alder";     
} elseif(!ctype_digit($input_spiller_alder)){
    $spiller_alder_err = 'Angiv venligst et tal';
} else{
    $spiller_alder = $input_spiller_alder;
}

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($spiller_navn_err) && empty($spiller_position_err) && empty($spiller_alder_err)){
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "UPDATE nbabdl_spiller SET spiller_navn=?, spiller_position=?, spiller_alder=? WHERE spiller_id=?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $param_spiller_navn, $param_spiller_position, $param_spiller_alder, $param_spiller_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_spiller_navn = $spiller_navn;
        $param_spiller_position = $spiller_position;
        $param_spiller_alder = $spiller_alder;
        $param_spiller_id = $spiller_id;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: bdl_index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Ups. Noget gik galt - prøv igen.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
} else{
// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["spiller_id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["spiller_id"]))){
    // Get URL parameter
    $spiller_id =  trim($_GET["spiller_id"]);

    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nbabdl_spiller WHERE spiller_id = ?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_spiller_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_spiller_id = $spiller_id;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                // Retrieve individual field value
                $spiller_navn = $row["spiller_navn"];
                $spiller_position = $row["spiller_position"];
                $spiller_alder = $row["spiller_alder"];
            } else{
                // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                header("location: bdl_error.php");
                exit();
            }

        } else{
            echo "Ups! Noget gik galt - prøv igen.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}  else{
    // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
    header("location: bdl_error.php");
    exit();
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Opdater spiller</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Opdater spiller</h2>
                </div>
                <p>Opdater spiller her</p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_navn_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Navn</label>
                        <input type="text" name="spiller_navn" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spiller_navn; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_navn_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_position_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Position</label>
                        <textarea name="spiller_position" class="form-control"><?php echo $spiller_position; ?></textarea>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_position_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_alder_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Alder</label>
                        <input type="text" name="spiller_alder" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spiller_alder; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_alder_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="spiller_id" value="<?php echo $spiller_id; ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    <a href="bdl_index.php" class="btn btn-default">Nulstil</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And now the code that is not working, with the added spiller_ligahold:

```
<?php

// Include config file
require_once 'bdl_config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$spiller_navn = $spiller_position = $spiller_alder = $spiller_ligahold = "";
$spiller_navn_err = $spiller_position_err = $spiller_alder_err = 
$spiller_ligahold_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["spiller_id"]) && !empty($_POST["spiller_id"])){
// Get hidden input value
$spiller_id = $_POST["spiller_id"];

// Validate Navn
$input_spiller_navn = trim($_POST["spiller_navn"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_navn)){
    $spiller_navn_err = "Angiv venligst et navn.";
} elseif(!filter_var(trim($_POST["spiller_navn"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z'-.\s ]+$/")))){
    $spiller_navn_err = 'Angiv venligst et gyldigt navn.';
} else{
    $spiller_navn = $input_spiller_navn;
}

// Validate Position
$input_spiller_position = trim($_POST["spiller_position"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_position)){
    $spiller_position_err = 'Angiv venligst en position.';     
} else{
    $spiller_position = $input_spiller_position;
}

// Validate Alder
$input_spiller_alder = trim($_POST["spiller_alder"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_alder)){
    $spiller_alder_err = "Angiv venligst en alder";     
} elseif(!ctype_digit($input_spiller_alder)){
    $spiller_alder_err = 'Angiv venligst et tal';
} else{
    $spiller_alder = $input_spiller_alder;
}
    // Validate Hold
$input_spiller_ligahold = trim($_POST["spiller_ligahold"]);
if(empty($input_spiller_ligahold)){
    $spiller_ligahold_err = 'Angiv venligst et hold.';     
} else{
    $spiller_ligahold = $input_spiller_ligahold;
}

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($spiller_navn_err) && empty($spiller_position_err) && empty($spiller_alder_err) && empty($spiller_ligahold_err)){
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "UPDATE nbabdl_spiller SET spiller_navn=?, spiller_position=?, spiller_alder=?, spiller_ligahold=? WHERE spiller_id=?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiis", $param_spiller_navn, $param_spiller_position, $param_spiller_alder, $param_spiller_id, $param_spiller_ligahold);

        // Set parameters
        $param_spiller_navn = $spiller_navn;
        $param_spiller_position = $spiller_position;
        $param_spiller_alder = $spiller_alder;
        $param_spiller_id = $spiller_id;
        $param_spiller_ligahold = $spiller_ligahold;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: bdl_index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Ups. Noget gik galt - prøv igen.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
} else{
// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["spiller_id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["spiller_id"]))){
    // Get URL parameter
    $spiller_id =  trim($_GET["spiller_id"]);

    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nbabdl_spiller WHERE spiller_id = ?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_spiller_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_spiller_id = $spiller_id;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                // Retrieve individual field value
                $spiller_navn = $row["spiller_navn"];
                $spiller_position = $row["spiller_position"];
                $spiller_alder = $row["spiller_alder"];
                $spiller_ligahold = $row["spiller_ligahold"];

            } else{
                // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                header("location: bdl_error.php");
                exit();
            }

        } else{
            echo "Ups! Noget gik galt - prøv igen.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}  else{
    // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
    header("location: bdl_error.php");
    exit();
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Opdater spiller</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Opdater spiller</h2>
                </div>
                <p>Opdater spiller her</p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_navn_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Navn</label>
                        <input type="text" name="spiller_navn" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spiller_navn; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_navn_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_position_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Position</label>
                        <textarea name="spiller_position" class="form-control"><?php echo $spiller_position; ?></textarea>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_position_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_alder_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Alder</label>
                        <input type="text" name="spiller_alder" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spiller_alder; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_alder_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($spiller_ligahold_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Tilhører</label>
                        <input type="text" name="spiller_ligahold" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $spiller_ligahold; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $spiller_ligahold_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="spiller_id" value="<?php echo $spiller_id; ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    <a href="bdl_index.php" class="btn btn-default">Tilbage</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

bdl_index.php:

```
<?php


echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css'>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>
    .wrapper{
        width: 650px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .page-header h2{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    table tr td:last-child a{
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle='tooltip']').tooltip();   
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <div class='page-header clearfix'>
                    <h2 class='pull-left'>NBABDL SPILLERE</h2>
                    <a href='bdl_create.php' class='btn btn-success pull-right'>Tilføj ny spiller</a>
                </div>";
                ?>
                <?php
                // Include config file
                require_once 'bdl_config.php';

                // Attempt select query execution
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM nbabdl_spiller ORDER BY spiller_navn";
                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";

                                    echo "<th>Navn</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Pos</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Alder</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Tilhører</th>";
                                    echo "<th>17-18</th>";
                                    echo "<th>18-19</th>";
                                    echo "<th>19-20</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Rediger</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                     echo "<td>" . $row['spiller_navn'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['spiller_position'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['spiller_alder'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['spiller_ligahold'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . number_format($row['spiller_lon1']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . number_format($row['spiller_lon2']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . number_format($row['spiller_lon3']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<a href='bdl_read.php?spiller_id=". $row['spiller_id'] ."' title='Vis spiller' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='bdl_update.php?spiller_id=". $row['spiller_id'] ."' title='Opdater spiller' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='bdl_delete.php?spiller_id=". $row['spiller_id'] ."' title='Slet spiller' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                    echo "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</tbody>";                            
                        echo "</table>";
                        // Free result set
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>Ingen nye spillere fundet.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }

                // Close connection
                mysqli_close($link);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a pretty decent amount of code. You need to strip away everything that's not relevant to the actual issue. Not many people will go through it all to try and find where the problem code is. Currently, it's the code version of "Where's Waldo".

Comment: A lot of the code you pasted has nothing to do with the question. Please clean up the appropriate code. Also, please don't echo all the things. It's just a mess that's hard to maintain. Use raw html when appropriate and use php in the server but preferably by using the client (javascript) to get and post the data needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the parameters are incorrect when you bind them to the prepared statement:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiis", $param_spiller_navn, $param_spiller_position, $param_spiller_alder, $param_spiller_id, $param_spiller_ligahold);
```

The last parameter is the `$param_spiller_ligahold`, whereas it should be the `$param_spiller_id`, since that's the last parameter in the sql statement:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiis", $param_spiller_navn, $param_spiller_position, $param_spiller_alder, $param_spiller_ligahold, $param_spiller_id );
```